# jquery ajax request wrapped in jQuery()'s .text() isn't the same as the div's .text()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this is a very concrete issue but I've struggled with this code for the last 2 hours and I can't find anything on the topic or figure out how to solve it.

I have an issue with a jQuery Ajax Post request. I am trying to make a section on my page where I display the users current level. When a user interacts and does something that increases the level on the site the level should also increase in the DOM/client's browser. Therefore I've added a setinterval that allows the request to run every 5th second. And if the $(response).text() is different from the current div's .text() where i am rendering the current level I want to append this new response from the ajax request.

Maybe the answer is more obvious than I think.... I have added the code below

Ajax page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getLevel() {

        var getLvlData = $.ajax({
            url: "AjaxRequests.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {type: "4", lvl_r_type: 1}
        });

        getLvlData.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var innerLevelHTML = $("#LevelContainer");

            if (($(response).text()) != ($(innerLevelHTML).text())) {
                innerLevelHTML.html("");
                innerLevelHTML.append(response);

            }
            if ($(response).text() == $(innerLevelHTML).text()) {
                alert("the same");
            }
        });

    }

    var levelChecker = setInterval(function () {
        getLevel();
    }, 1000);
    getLevel();

});
```

AjaxRequests.php:

```
    if ($_POST["type"] == "4" && isset($_POST["lvl_r_type"])) {

                $returnVal = htmlentities($_POST["lvl_r_type"]);

                if (!empty($returnVal)) {
                    if ($returnVal == 1) {

                ?>

                    <div id="chartWrapper">
                        <div>
                            <canvas id="doughnut-chart"></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <div id="chart-center">
                            <div>
                                <div><h1>0%</h1></div>
                                <div><p>GX 0 / 1</p></div>
                            </div>
                            <div><p>LVL 0</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="progressList">
                        <div><p>View tasks</p></div>
                    </div>

                <?php 

                        } 
         }
}
    ?>
```

html page

```
                    <div id="LevelContainer"></div>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code, thanks.

Comment: Sry, guys. Give me 2 min

Comment: I have added the code now!

Comment: Could I ask you to please update your title because `request.text()` is a valid method for the `fetch` API, and not valid for the jqXHR object it's `jQuery().text` on `jqXHR response` does not match text already in HTML when it should

Comment: @PoulBak thats just utterly pointless call of jQuery to convert HTML String to a DOM Object and then back to a HTML string when you can put a string into `jQuery().html()` it should be `innerLevelHTML.html(response);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using trim since a white space could be treated as a part of the text.

```
if (($(response).text().trim()) != ($(innerLevelHTML).text().trim())) {
...
```

One alternative approach I can think of, off of my head is, to set a hash inside a data attribute say `data-hash=""` whenever you set the html of that div, and then whenever you have a new ajax response you can generate a hash on the fly and compare that to the existing one and if a change is found just update the html and the hash value for that attribute.

This process minimises the confusion that may be caused due to dom being updated by some script.

Also, Instead of

```
innerLevelHTML.html("");
innerLevelHTML.append(response);
```

Why not just just set the html directly as

```
innerLevelHTML.html(response);
```

Comment: Your answer's strapline is just wrong. from the offset if you put HTML text as a response is into a the jQuery function `jQuery(...)` or `$(...)` it will create a DOM Element for you, to test this do `$("<div></div>");` while I do agree with your answers main point about using `.html()` it's cleaner and more efficient to just overnight the content once you have the text in memory already. so please remove your first line as it's not true.

Comment: Ahh it does work...My bad, Updated my answer. I don't know how I missed that. :)

Comment: I think I now know why you missed it, because the title is wrong and suggest that the OP is using .text on a jqXHR when they are not.

Comment: He he, on point, my thought process was pretty much something along those lines... thanks.